# Upgrading ember application to 3.0 unexpected token <<

Tags: ember.js, vagrant, syntax-error, upgrade, stack-trace

Gradually upgrading Ember application from 2.13 to latest version but going from 2.13 to 2.16 I am encountering an error that is difficult to figure. I am using Vagrant with virtualbox to run the application in a development environment.

Application works fine in version 2.13 but getting the error once I vagrant ssh into app at 2.16

The error is...

```
Unexpected token <<


Stack Trace and Error Report: 
/tmp/error.dump.f76b3982a2d9321c6b6ac71c816e3899.log
An error occurred in the constructor for ember-resolver at 
/vagrant/node_modules/ember-resolver

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gt-ember-sso@0.6.0 start-vm: `ember server --live-reload- 
port=9999 --watcher polling`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gt-ember-sso@0.6.0 start-vm script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-05-16T15_55_58_371Z- 
debug.log
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

I am using ember-reolver addon in the application the version of this addon is ^4.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This likely isn't related to Ember - I would check for an incomplete git merge - search your code for `<<<` and see if any of the files contain that and remove (resolve) the merge issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right using VS Code was able to resolve the merge conflicts easily & upgraded the application. Thanks!

Comment: `Unexpected token {


Stack Trace and Error Report: /var/folders/2y/v3ykvw751rj8c2zv4vl8q8cm0000gn/T/error.dump.514146f0c2c574c16ad3ef54952bc7f3.log`

I'm facing the same issue? but how can i resolve the conflict?